# after start the angular project visual studio shows typescript errors in lib.dom.d.ts file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017, tslint

i have angular project , the project run from VS 2017  .. but showing too much errors (tslint error) for typescript file located on C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\3.2\lib.dom.d.ts

after run the project the visual studio show errors but the website works

how i can disable this errors ?
[image: s]

tsconfig.js file:

```
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      { "name": "tslint-language-service" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Add `"ignoreDefinitionFiles": true` to your `tslint.json`.  what is happening is that the linter is checking the DTS files.  more information may be necessary to answer this

Comment: still have same problem

Comment: Run `./node_modules/.bin/tsc` from the directory containing `tsconfig.json` to rule out VS being the issue